# Macbook Kernel Panic GT should be out of RC6

Tags: macos, kernel

I am getting this strange kernel crash, **GT should be out of RC6** when my computer is asleep. I have a MacBook 2016 running MacOS Sierra. I thought maybe an app may be causing this but i can't find any reference to anything.

```
Anonymous UUID:       E87741C5-3B63-C07F-7C42-BB2EB9E8E362

Wed Oct  5 23:20:28 2016

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 3 caller 0xffffff7f885450c5): "GT should be out of RC6, but FORCEWAKE_MULTITHREADED register [15:0] = 0, full register = 0x10000\n"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/GPUDriversIntel/GPUDriversIntel-10.18.65/Common/GLKernel/Intel/skl/sched3/IGGuC.cpp:1339
Backtrace (CPU 3), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff913d97b970 : 0xffffff8005cf748c 
0xffffff913d97b9f0 : 0xffffff7f885450c5 
0xffffff913d97bae0 : 0xffffff7f88546290 
0xffffff913d97bb40 : 0xffffff7f8855a89c 
0xffffff913d97bb60 : 0xffffff7f882deedc 
0xffffff913d97bba0 : 0xffffff7f882e4b31 
0xffffff913d97bbf0 : 0xffffff7f8661ffb5 
0xffffff913d97bc40 : 0xffffff7f86620c52 
0xffffff913d97bc70 : 0xffffff7f88366a95 
0xffffff913d97bd60 : 0xffffff7f88376f2f 
0xffffff913d97bdb0 : 0xffffff7f883771e2 
0xffffff913d97be00 : 0xffffff7f866222db 
0xffffff913d97be40 : 0xffffff7f86621476 
0xffffff913d97be80 : 0xffffff7f8661d373 
0xffffff913d97bee0 : 0xffffff80062bedbf 
0xffffff913d97bf30 : 0xffffff80062bd621 
0xffffff913d97bf80 : 0xffffff80062bcc06 
0xffffff913d97bfb0 : 0xffffff8005ca6af7 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[377FAA09-C02F-3FF4-A5DE-C0F2E711C8B0]@0xffffff7f86612000->0xffffff7f8664cfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[731443D8-78D5-30C8-939A-1ED3E857CA22]@0xffffff7f86532000
         com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(288.13)[27E0AFCE-E36A-35F5-A008-BB1EB3A2C7B9]@0xffffff7f882b0000->0xffffff7f88340fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[731443D8-78D5-30C8-939A-1ED3E857CA22]@0xffffff7f86532000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[377FAA09-C02F-3FF4-A5DE-C0F2E711C8B0]@0xffffff7f86612000
         com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSKLGraphicsFramebuffer(10.1.8)[79FA4A62-0C04-31CC-87EC-2F6FF665DD48]@0xffffff7f8835c000->0xffffff7f88508fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[731443D8-78D5-30C8-939A-1ED3E857CA22]@0xffffff7f86532000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[4F7FB6AD-2498-3F71-827C-ED7AA4BF2511]@0xffffff7f86b85000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(288.13)[27E0AFCE-E36A-35F5-A008-BB1EB3A2C7B9]@0xffffff7f882b0000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily(31)[3CAF0CDE-3EB5-32C8-91EF-EC5C7CAFBA22]@0xffffff7f870ef000
            dependency: com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(3.13.60)[FDEAB5E1-3BFF-34DF-92AB-6AE26C8405F7]@0xffffff7f88350000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[377FAA09-C02F-3FF4-A5DE-C0F2E711C8B0]@0xffffff7f86612000
         com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSKLGraphics(10.1.8)[428198BA-0CE2-3674-8C49-2E47B6F49479]@0xffffff7f88531000->0xffffff7f885ecfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(152)[CD2E7A07-1BD9-3298-A038-E6F8098F0C2A]@0xffffff7f87062000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[731443D8-78D5-30C8-939A-1ED3E857CA22]@0xffffff7f86532000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[377FAA09-C02F-3FF4-A5DE-C0F2E711C8B0]@0xffffff7f86612000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(288.13)[27E0AFCE-E36A-35F5-A008-BB1EB3A2C7B9]@0xffffff7f882b0000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
16A323

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 16.0.0: Mon Aug 29 17:56:20 PDT 2016; root:xnu-3789.1.32~3/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 622D2470-C34D-31F9-A62B-6AA9A3C6A3CD
Kernel slide:     0x0000000005a00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8005c00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8005b00000
System model name: MacBook9,1 (Mac-9AE82516C7C6B903)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 54986053018105
last loaded kext at 54268289963729: com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3 (addr 0xffffff7f88d22000, size 32768)
last unloaded kext at 52909867586712: com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme  3 (addr 0xffffff7f88d22000, size 32768)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  5.0.16
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  5.0.16
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 5.0.16
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 5.0.16
com.radiosilenceapp.nke.filter  2.0
com.kairos.driver.DuetDisplay   1
zoom.us.ZoomAudioDevice 1.2
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.1
com.apple.filesystems.afpfs 11.0.1
com.apple.nke.asp-tcp   8.0.1
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.7
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.13.60
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.4
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   276.26
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSKLGraphics  10.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelPCHPMC   1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.9.10
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSKLGraphicsFramebuffer   10.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    208
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.13
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    5.0.0f18
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface   5.57.0
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 39
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  366.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 102
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1100.37.1a16
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   171
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.security.SecureRemotePassword 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 900.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.1
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUARTTransport  5.0.0f18
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  5.0.0f18
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 276.26
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   152
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.13.60
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.13.60
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    288.13
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 276.26
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 276.26
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   205.11
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.14d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   5.0.0f18
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssUARTv1   3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssUARTCommon   3.0.60
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   394
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    540
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   197
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  367.6
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    76.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPIHIDDriver    49
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPISupport  49
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssSpiController    3.0.60
com.apple.iokit.IONVMeFamily    2.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPM   3.0.8
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2CController    3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssDmac 3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2C  3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssGspi 3.0.60
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 444
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  5.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
Model: MacBook9,1, BootROM MB91.0154.B07, 2 processors, Intel Core m7, 1.3 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.35f102
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 515, Intel HD Graphics 515, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, LPDDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4B33514634463430424D2D41474346202020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, LPDDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4B33514634463430424D2D41474346202020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x158), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.171.10.1a16)
Bluetooth: Version 5.0.0f18, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wifi, AirPort, en0
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

Answer (score 0):

You might wish to try resetting your PRRAM and SMC controller. This fixes a lot of problems on MacOS relating to Sleep and especially after system upgrades (like moving up to Sierra). I had to reset both several times to finally get my system to stop core dumping and boot and function properly.

Comment: Ill give it a go and see how it goes.